# How to pass a variable number of variables into a pyspark select expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have a simple pyspark function

```
features=['x', 'y', 'z']
def f(features):
    df.groupBy('id').agg(collect_list(features[0]), collect_list(features[1]), ....)
```

I want it so that if someone passes in features=['x', 'y', 'z', 'a'] each thing in features will have its own collect_list function in the agg function.  How can I do this?  They all have to be in the same agg function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
features=['x', 'y', 'z']
def f(features):
    df.groupBy("id").agg(*[collect_list(feature) for feature in features ])
```

`features` array elements will be iterated inside `agg` function, and one aggregated column will be created for each feature.

To derive custom column names for the aggregated columns,

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(*[F.collect_list(feature).alias("%s_list" % (feature)) for feature in features ])
```

Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784146/how-can-i-concatenate-the-rows-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-with-multiple-columns-usin/62784297#62784297) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Try to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62784966/edit) your answer to include details about the code. Thanks!